# If recycler view is not recycled, is it inefficient to use recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

[image]

I am making a screen like a picture. The background color is white, so you can't see it, but it's a `dialog window`. (The picture is a comment I entered arbitrarily)

As in the picture, the dialog consists of a `RecyclerView`.
Up to `5 items` can be created.

All the items are listed in the photo, but when i open the dialog for the first time, there is only one item, and when i press the `enter key` in the first comment, the next item is `dynamically created`.

Comments can only be entered with a maximum of `one` line.

The key here is that it has a maximum of `5` items unconditionally.

Very few items.

So there will be no `scrolling` and therefore `no recycling` is expected.

Is it okay to use Recycler View in this situation?

Some people say that there is no advantage to using `RecyclerView` as it is not recycled.

I used `addView()` as an alternative, but it doesn't work the way I want it to be because I wrote the code incorrectly.

Is there really no reason to use `RecyclerView` if the item is not recycled?

Or tell me a good idea for my function

(If you want, I will upload the code that used addView())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I would say it is absolutely okay to use `RecyclerView` in this instance. It obviously is not built for this purpose and would generally take more time to implement than a simple solution as you mentioned with `addView(View)`, however if the code is already written and it is working the way you want it to, I see no reason to over-complicate things.

To address specifically your concern with efficiency, I am sure there will be a theoretical small performance hit, but I wouldn't recommend focusing time into optimisation if the payoff is small and there isn't a performance issue in the first place.

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil - Donald Knuth

---

As a side note, in reference to the answer from @Primož Ivančič, there is no reason to use `RecyclerView`, but since you have already taken the time to implement it, there is probably no reason not to.

Comment: Does that mean that using RecyclerView is not suitable in my case?

Comment: As my answer says, I think that using `RecyclerView` is definitely suitable. Just because you are not leveraging all the features from the component doesn't mean it's inappropriate. If we are talking about raw performance, you have to consider whether replacing something that is already in place is worth the extra performance gains (which in this case I think would be completely unnoticeable).

Comment: OK, i understood, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any advantage to using `RecyclerView`. Items are too few to be recycled. And even if they are, there's still only five of them.

I would probably use `LinearLayout` and added items in there with `addView()` and wrapped `LinearLayout` into `ScrollView` (user might have a small device and font set to the biggest).

Why? Implementing `RecyclerView` means quite some of code. And if that code is only used for displaying 5 items, I don't think it is worth it. It's easier to just add views into `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Do you mean, as I wrote in the content, is it better to use `addView()`?

Comment: I would almost certainly do that.

Comment: However, when using `addView()`, there should be one item at first when the dialog window is opened.

However, since the `EnterKey event` is implemented on the first item, the event only works for this first item.

Additional events do not work for items after using `addView()`.
What should I do?

Comment: For the events, please open another question (and maybe link it here) as it is completely other issue as the title of this question states.